# Subir Imagen con ajax sin jquery (javascript puro) a servidor php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, fileupload

Estoy intentando subir una imagen a mi servidor php usando ajax pero con javascript puro (sin Jquery). Les dejo el formulario, la funcion js y el archivo php.

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="titulo">Titulo</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="titulo">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="articulo">Articulo</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="articulo" id="articulo">
                </div>
                Subir Imagen
                <input class="form-control" type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
                <button class="btn btn-light my-2" id="insertar">Insertar Datos</button>
            </form>
```

Aca mi archivo JS

```
document.getElementById("insertar").addEventListener("click", insertarDatos());
function insertarDatos(e) {
    var titulo = document.getElementById('titulo').value,
        artirulo = document.getElementById('articulo').value,
        imagen = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').value,
        datos = "ajax=2&titulo=" + titulo +
        "&articulo=" + artirulo +
        "&imagen=" + imagen;
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("POST", "index.php", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    xhttp.send(datos);
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var respuesta = this.response;
            console.log(respuesta);
        }
    };
}
```

y aca esta mi archivo php en el que solo quiero comprobar que me lleva el archivo (en este caso imagen) con un var_dump($_FILES)

```
elseif ($_POST['ajax'] == 2) {
$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
$articulo = $_POST['articulo'];
$imagen = $_POST['imagen'];
var_dump($_FILES);}
```

Espero Puedan ayudarme. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias opciones, como usar *fileReader* o [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/Usando_Objetos_FormData) y, la verdad, prefiero la segunda, porque es mucho más fácil de lo que te imaginas.

Para comenzar, asigna ID al formulario, para poder tomar todos los campos y agregarlos al objeto *FormData*, luego puedes agregar otras variables, en tu caso solo `ajax=2`

```js
document.getElementById("insertar").addEventListener("click", insertarDatos);
function insertarDatos(e) {
    // Evitar que se procese el formulario
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // Crear variable de formulario
    let formSubir = document.querySelector('#formSubir');
    // Poner todos los campos del formulario en FormData
    let datos = new FormData(formSubir);
    // Agregar ajax=2
    datos.append('ajax', 2);
    // Si quieres ver los datos:
    console.log([...datos]);
    
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("POST", "index.php", true);

    // Este encabezado es para peticiones por GET, no lo uses
    // xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

    // Primero se define la función para analizar resultado
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var respuesta = this.response;
            console.log(respuesta);
        }
    };
    // Después se envían los datos
    xhttp.send(datos);
}
```

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formSubir">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="titulo">Titulo</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="titulo">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="articulo">Articulo</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="articulo" id="articulo">
                </div>
                Subir Imagen
                <input class="form-control" type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
                <button class="btn btn-light my-2" id="insertar">Insertar Datos</button>
            </form>
```

Con esto vas a recibir los datos en PHP como lo tienes ahora.

**Nota:** Cuando agregues funciones a eventos no uses paréntesis, porque se ejecutará inmediatamente:

> `document.getElementById("insertar").addEventListener("click", insertarDatos());`

En su lugar, solo pon el nombre:

> `document.getElementById("insertar").addEventListener("click", insertarDatos);`

Comment: ¿Cómo hago para que no se refresque la página cuando se envían los datos?